# how to hide comment in office js?

Tags: office-js, office-addins

I am developing an add-in office js using react which contain many commented cell. I successfully create a comment but it displays on cell and on hover it displays. I want to hide this comment using office js but can't find a similar this in the Microsoft office document.

[image]

I have also google find a post
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-programmatically-display-worksheet-comments?view=vs-2019

Comment: Thanks very much for reporting the issue. Current we don't have this kind of API yet. Could you help to submit a request under https://aka.ms/m365dev-suggestions? Then our PM will track it and assign priority. Thanks!

Comment: okay, thank you.